# "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to make a Tic Tac Toe game following [this](https://mostafa-samir.github.io/Tic-Tac-Toe-AI/) tutorial. When I run it and look at the Chrome dev tools, it says `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`, and point me to the line of this function:

```
var State = function(oldState) {
    this.turn = "";
    this.oMovesCount = 0;
    this.result = "still running";
    this.board = [];


    //get the information from the previous state to use it for following states
    if (typeof oldState !== "undefined") {
        var len = oldState.board.length;
        this.board = new Array(len);
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            this.board[i] = oldState.board[i];
        }
        this.oMovesCount = oldState.oMovesCount;
        this.result = oldState.result;
        this.turn = oldState.turn;
    }

    //change to X or O accordingly
    this.advanceTurn = function() {
        //Was it just X's turn? If so, change to O. If not, change to X.
        this.turn = this.turn === "x" ? "o" : "x";
    };

    //checks for victory
    this.result = "still running";
    this.isTerminal = function() {
        var B = this.board;

        //check to see if there has been a victory
        //check rows
        for(var i = 0; i <= 6; i = i + 3) {
            if(B[i] !== "E" && B[i] === B[i+1] && B[i+1] == B[i+2]) {
                this.result = B[i] + " has won!";
                return true;
            }
        }
        //check columns
        for(var i = 0; i <= 2 ; i++) {
            if(B[i] !== "E" && B[i] === B[i+3] && B[i+3] === B[i+6]) {
                this.result = B[i] + " has won!";
                return true;
            }
        }
        //check diagonals
        for(var i = 0, j = 4; i <= 2 ; i = i + 2, j = j - 2) {
            if(B[i] !== "E" && B[i] == B[i+j] && B[i+j] === B[i + 2*j]) {
                this.result = B[i] + " has won!";
                return true;
            }
        };

        //if there have been no wins, check the number of empty cells
        //if there are no empty cells, it's a draw
        var available = this.emptyCells();
        if (available.length == 0) {
            this.result = "draw";
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    };
    //keeps track of how many empty cells there are on the board
    this.emptyCells = function() {
        var indxs = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (this.board[i] === "E") {
                indxs.push(i);
            }
        }
        return indxs;
    } 
};
```

I don't understand why. [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/nmo1j4o0/) the full code, the error shows up when you click `Play` then `OK` then on one of the cells. [Here](http://tictacttoegame5.bitballoon.com/) it is hosted on another site if it helps.

Thank you!

Comment: Wrong fiddle, or you didn't copy the actual code. Getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined", not what you say.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yep, click play and ok, and then on any of the cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the AIAction method:

```
this.oMovesPosition = pos; //the position on the board where the O would be placed
this.minimaxVal = 0; //the minimax value of the state that the action leads to

this.applyTo = function(state) {
    var next = new State(state);

    //if the current turn in the current state is O, increment .oMovesCount
    next.board[this.movePosition] = state.turn;
    if (state.turn === "o") {
        next.oMovesCount++;
    }
    next.advanceTurn();
    return next;
};
```

Notice  the this.oMovesPosition in the first line, but then the applyTo method refers to this.movePosition instead.

Comment: I don't think that was a mistake; the tutorial I'm following does the same thing.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. This is the correct answer (+1). `this.movePosition` will always be `undefined`. Check it with debugging. Tutorials are not perfect.

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Too recursion, in fiddle line 395 you call the function minimax in recursion.

```
var nextScore = miniMax(nextState);
```

You must stop recursion before run out of memory, or convert the recursion into a loop.

Comment: Excuse my lack of knowledge, but how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In `AIaction = function(pos)` you have two spellings for what should be the same `movePosition` property:

```
this.oMovesPosition = pos;
```

and:

```
next.board[this.movePosition] = state.turn;
```

Because they are different properties, the second line will always be equivalent to this:

```
next.board[undefined] = state.turn;
```

... and so the board never actually changes. As a consequence a board is never considered terminal, and your recursion never stops.